# LuaLatex and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I am having some difficulties with LuaLatex and TikZ.  Can some explain to me what is wrong with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{luacode} % read this somewhere, doesn't change anything.
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{Some sections}
  Some random text.

  \directlua{ tex.print([=[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
      \draw (0,0) to (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}]=])
  }

\end{document}
```

The same kind of Lua code works when used from an external script. But like this it gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GTS@RemoveLeft ...{}{}\GTS@Nil }\edef \GTS@Token
```

Comment: Did you read [`luacode` documentation](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/luatex/latex/luacode/luacode.pdf)? Section 1.1 gives some explanations...

Comment: No I had not. Will do now. Changing `\directlua` to `\luadirect` didn't do anything. Will read the rest now ;)

Comment: Ok, this solved the problem: use `luacode*` environment. I don't need expansion of TeX macros so this is easiest since single `\\` just work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative coding with `luacode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tp=tex.print
tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]")
tp("\\draw (0,0) to (1,1);")
tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
}
\end{document}
```